# Windows 8 Store App - Memory footprint too high

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps, winjs, memory-footprint

I am building a WinJS Windows 8 Store App, and im having problems with keeping the "Memory Footprint" low, as currently it fails the "Performance Analyzer for HTML5 Apps":

> **Memory Footprint**
>
> Apps run better when they use a small amount of
>   memory. An app should have a memory footprint of less than 60MB. To
>   reduce your app's memory footprint, avoid keeping references to
>   objects, such as images or blobs, that are no longer needed.
>
> RESULT: *app* reference set is 112MB; working set is 98MB. This
>   exceeds the 80MB reference set maximum and 80MB working set maximum
>   failure threshold.

I looking for any tips on how to deal with this, and i don't see where this 112MB comes from, looking in the Task Manager, my app never exceeds more then ~50MB.

Thanks!

If you need anymore info just ask, not sure what to provide.

Comment: Is the build you're testing debug or release? That may make a difference in the memory size you're seeing.

Comment: Did you use the JavaScript Memory analysis tools that were recently released for VS2012? this will allow you to detect leaks.

Comment: this was release, and i have been using the Javascript Memory tools, whilst they are helpful to show how you app reacts as you use it, showing how much memory increases etc (which mine doesn't really grow in memory). It feels like finding a needle in a haystack for finding why it is high in the 1st place.

Comment: Also, doing some research, i came across this article on "Windows 8 app developer blog" (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/04/03/how-to-improve-performance-in-your-metro-style-app.aspx) there it states:

App complexity (approx.)
Total working set (max)
Minimal app (ex. Hello World)
50-70 MB
Medium app (ex. Weather)
80-100 MB
Large app (ex. Photos)
120-150 MB

And my app is in the Medium app, in terms of complexity

Comment: As another tip I'd recommend Andrew Hall's BUILD session "Diagnosing performance and memory issues in JavaScript-based Windows Store apps" (http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/3-008). Andrew covers these tools and offers recommendations throughout.

Comment: CLEAN UP... whenever you create a new page or view remove listeners and destroy cached elements. These simple rules of thumb can reduce footprint dramatically and significantly help with DOM performance. In a defined pages unload function always remove handlers and elements.

Comment: Reallly? It should not be that big at all. If your package is that big your probably doing something wrong. Meh...... Seems like resources are not being destroyed. Are there a lot of high density graphics in your app? Whenever you create a new page or view, remove listeners, references to assets, and destroy cached elements. Its always best to pre-load assets and reuse them where possible, and use vector drawing and bit-map caching where applicable. These simple rules of thumb can reduce footprint dramatically and significantly help with DOM performance.

Answer (score 0):

My small app C#/XAML is already taking ~100 MB, seems that the underlying sandbox/CLR is responsible for most of this. Good thing that  Metro apps have agressive memory managment from the OS, as soons as they're out of sight they're suspended and partially removed from memory.

Update: It seems MS documentation was right, by cleaning the datasets (lists of objects and strings, mostly), the memory use drops drastically. I went from 120 MB to 30 MB, much more manageable and with room to breath.